# Could not load SharePoint Online List - Expected double-quoted property name in JSON at position xxx (line xxx column xxx)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

Sometimes SharePoint Online throws me an error like this -  `Expected double-quoted property name in JSON at position xxx (line xxx column xxx)`, I mentioned the Image below.

[image]

It's a throw only sometimes, **what is the actual problem?**

**So, what is the solution for this?**

Comment: Are you using JSON column/view formatting in your list? Or any other custom functionality?

Comment: No, I have no use in anything like JSON column/view Formatting and no custom functionality. I just created a list, and this thing is also happening with all other lists at the same time. and If I reload the page after 3-5 min then it will work properly.

Comment: Then it maybe some issue from Microsoft's end. Raise a support ticket with Microsoft directly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide#online-support

Comment: Okay, Thank you for your help @GaneshSanap-MVP